# Get count of votes with Eloquent in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

i'm trying to get count of likes for each picture. Here is my code

```
$user = User::with(['pictures' => function($q){
        $q->with('likes')->count();
    }])
```

This code returns all likes as separately for each picture.

I think this count() is not working for me.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is likes a column name in pictures table?

Comment: likes is method name in Picture model. and references likes table

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::with(['pictures' => function($q){
        $q->where('likes',1)->count();
    }]);
```

Remember to specify a relationship in User Model like so:

```
class Country extends \Eloquent {

    public function pictures(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Picture');
    }

}
```

NB: I assumed App\Models\Picture is your pictures Model and also that 'likes' is Boolean datatype column in pictures table